# Separate iOS apps and icons for Testflight and production builds

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, bundle-identifier

I'd like to be able to have a debug/testflight version of my app on my phone as well as the app currently in production, but I'm not sure how to do that. I know it has something to do with the bundle IDs and macros and things, but I'm not really sure where to start, partially because I'm not sure what questions to ask.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bundle IDs must be different or the system will overwrite one app with the other when you install it.

Set up separate targets. For each target, use a different bundle ID, and different icon art files (or a different asset catalog). That should be all there is to it.

Comment: That's exactly what I do.  I typically have my test targets have a different app name (like "Staging") and the same icon as the original app, but in greyscale.

Comment: Doesn't Apple have to know about the new bundle ID so that you can push to TestFlight?